# Get the last 7 digits after the hyphen before the dot

Tags: php, regex

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
                    <a href="/projects/ar-na-vnutrennie-pomesheniya-ploshad-300-m2-1301919.html" target="_blank" title="Название">
                                                    <span title="Поднят" data-toggle="tooltip">
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-double-up"></i>
                            </span>
                                                АР на внутренние помещения, площадь 300 м2                    </a>
                
    [1] => 
                    <a href="/projects/verstka-pod-js-frejmvorki-na-postoyanku-1301909.html" target="_blank" title="Название">
                                                    <span title="Поднят" data-toggle="tooltip">
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-double-up"></i>
                            </span>
                                                Верстка под JS фреймворки на постоянку                    </a>
    ...
```

And I want to extract the 7-digit numbers after the hyphen and before the dot, so I get a result like:

```
[
    1301919,
    1301909,
    ...
]
```

In my code, I manage to extract the digits:

```
$terms = array();
foreach ($doc->find('.box-title h2') as $string) {
  $terms[] = pq($string)->html();
}
$new_array = [];
foreach ($terms as $item) {
    $new_array[] = strstr($item,'.html',true);
}
$new_array1 = [];
foreach ($new_array as $item1){
    $new_array1[] = preg_replace('/[\D]/', '', $item1);
}
return $new_array1;
```

I get:

```
[
    30021301919,
    1301909,
    91301886,
    1301865,
    1301863,
    1229911,
    241301847,
    ...
]
```

But this does not meet the condition for only extracting the ***last 7*** digits, and this solution needs two `foreach` loops.

For the first value, the correct option should be: 1301919

How can I get the desired value, and preferably in one `foreach` loop, possibly with a regular expression?

Comment: Use `preg_replace('~.*-(\d{7})\.[^.]*$~', '$1', $txt)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can even do it without `foreach` loop; using [`preg_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-filter.php):

```php
$new_array = preg_filter("#.*-(\d{7})\.html.*#is", "$1", $terms);
```

Comment: I always forget about `preg_filter` for some reason.

Comment: If I use it, I get some code after .html `Array
(
    [0] => 
1301919" target="_blank" title="Название">
                                                    <span title="Поднят" data-toggle="tooltip">
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-double-up"></i>
                            </span>
                                                АР на внутренние помещения, площадь 300 м2                    </a>
                `

Comment: How do I adjust the regex so that everything is deleted after the required seven digits?

Comment: Sure. Change the ending of the regex to `.*#is`. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

Just get 7 digits followed by a dot:

```
preg_match('/(\d{7})\./', $item, $match);
echo $match[1];
```

If it's always going to be `.html` then:

```
preg_match('/(\d{7})\.html$/', $item, $match);
echo $match[1];
```